# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in HighVoltage::Pages#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm set up high_voltage to create static pages within my app. However i've now added a new investment controller. I'm trying to create a link from application.html.erb to the controller, it's giving me the following error. I believe it's trying to route inside of High_Voltage (still kinda new to this)

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in HighVoltage::Pages#show
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"high_voltage/investments", :id=>"about"}
```

application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<li> <%= link_to 'About', page_path('about') %> </li>
<li> <%= link_to 'Real Estate', controller: 'investments' %></li>
```

routes.rb looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


devise_for :users
  devise_for :views
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
    get 'pages/index' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
    root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts
  resources :properties
  resources :articles
  resources :investments
end
```

I've tried all the other options on here without much success :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in application.html.erb for Real Estate link. Thanks

`<li> <%= link_to 'Real Estate', investments_path %></li>`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!